# how to call a static method from another class in JS

Tags: javascript, class, static

I need to calculate the area of 3 classes ( Square, rectangular, circle), with only 1 static method inside the `class AreaCalculator` . How can I achieve that?

```
  class Square {
  
  constructor(side) {
    this.sides = side;
  }
}

class Rectangle {
  constructor(width, height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }
}

class Circle {

  constructor(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
  }
}

class AreaCalculator {
  // ... static method to implement

}

const square = new Square(4);
const rectangle = new Rectangle(4, 2);
const circle = new Circle(5);

console.log(AreaCalculator.calculate(square));
console.log(AreaCalculator.calculate(rectangle));
console.log(AreaCalculator.calculate(circle));
```

Comment: what have you tried? is this a copy-paste of your homework?

Comment: figure out a way to identify what kind of class the object you're passing to the method came from and then apply your calculation

Comment: yes it is my homework. i can work on simple class and methods. But it is still difficult for me, specially understand the Static method. I was looking for some ints.

Comment: from my understanding. A static method is part of the class and can only be called when accessing it through the class and not through an instance. this also means that to access the method you don't have to initialize the class like you'd usually do. maybe this is a helpfull [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

Comment: yes thanks a lot. already watched that website, without success.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
static calculate(shape) {
        switch (shape.constructor.name) {
            case "Square": return shape.sides * shape.sides;
            case "Circle": return Math.PI * shape.radius * shape.radius;
            case "Rectangle": return shape.width * shape.height;
        }
    }
```